# How to convert EPSG:28992 to EPSG:4326?

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-systems, coordinate-transformation, epsg

I have a list of coordinates which i need to convert to longitude and latitude in the folowing way:

[image]

What are the math transformations and formulas used to achieve this?

Comment: This is not really a programming question, but you could find better answers on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/). You have all relevant information for the EPSG:28992 projection on [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/28992).

Answer (score 1):

QGis might also be helpful to convert between several projections.
Once you can see your geometry as layer in Qgis, right click on the layer and select
Export => Save Features As ... and select the wanted format.

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html